# How do bowlers adjust their tactics and bowling styles and length when transitioning from T20s to Test cricket

Tags: cricket, icc

Now that the World Test Championship final is going to be held, how do bowlers who have played in the IPL or any T20 suddenly adapt to test conditions within such a short duration? What strategies do they need to adapt to test cricket lines and lengths?